# How to query the ordinal index of each row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ordinals

Let say I have this table:

```
| Order ID |  User  |  Order Date |  
-----------------------------------  
|    1     | Dave   |  03/01/2017 |   
|    2     | Jim    |  03/09/2017 |  
|    3     | John   |  03/15/2017 |  
|    4     | John   |  03/18/2017 |  
|    5     | Jim    |  03/18/2017 |  
|    6     | Dave   |  03/30/2017 |  
|    7     | John   |  04/04/2017 |  
|    8     | Jim    |  04/16/2017 |
```

Things I want is to put one more column to indicate the n-th order per individual, because I need to analyze the repeated behavior of users.
So the output should be like this:

```
| Order ID |  User  |  Order Date | n-th |
-----------------------------------------  
|    1     | Dave   |  03/01/2017 |  1   | 
|    2     | Jim    |  03/09/2017 |  1   |
|    3     | John   |  03/15/2017 |  1   |
|    4     | John   |  03/18/2017 |  2   |
|    5     | Jim    |  03/18/2017 |  2   |
|    6     | Dave   |  03/30/2017 |  2   |
|    7     | John   |  04/04/2017 |  3   |
|    8     | Jim    |  04/16/2017 |  3   |
```

That means:

- order #1 is Dave's 1st order
- order #2 is Jim's 1st order
  ...
- order #5 is Jim's 2nd order

and so on!
How can I get this using raw query in SQL?
Thank you.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would use `row_number()`. In MySQL, this is best done using variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@u = user, @rn + 1,
                  if(@u := user, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as nth
from t cross join
     (select @u := '', @rn := 0) params
order by user, orderdate;
```

You can also formulate this query using a correlated subquery, but the method using variables should have better performance.

To get the data back in its original format, use the above as a subquery and then sort by the order id.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for you suggestion. But the output I expected as the my question above, the data is only sorted by OrderId, so the `n-th` per individual will be sparse in the whole result set.  
In your case, to make the `row_number` work then we have to re-sort the output by `user` first

Comment: @ĐinhHồngChâu . . . Just use the above as subquery and then order however you like.